# Uploading image file in canvas and broadcasting it to clients using socket.emit in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I just like to broadcast an image from server to client.

I can upload the image at one end of the client. But its not reflecting on the other side.
What snippet I have to include to make these things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not use Socket.IO for high payload streaming (like pictures).

Try this:

In your server:

```
var socket = require('socket.io'),
    io = socket.listen(yourApp);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {

  client.on('imageUploaded', function(imgURL) {
    client.broadcast.emit('imageBroadcast', imgURL);    
  });

});
```

In your client:

```
var server = io.connect(yourServerIp);

// You image upload logic here. You can get the URL after uploading and then you call this function:
function imageUploaded(url){
  server.emit('imageUploaded', url);
}

server.on('imageBroadcast', function(imgURL){
  // Here you decide what to do with the image
});
```

Comment: actually I can't get the flow of the code. Can uexplain in detail how the code works?? And in the "imgURL" what is the thing to sent in the fuction as parameter. Is the exact URL of the image??

Comment: Thanks for your info. As per your idea I have did everything. its working for url's like "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg".But if i gave local resource it's giving me the error in console as "Not able to load local resource".. How this can be solved ?

Comment: No problem, @user1932130 I'd appreciate that you mark this as the correct answer if this was useful for you.

As for your resources problem, I think the easiest way is to put the resources you need to share in the public directory. At least it will work if you are using Express.

Comment: ohhh I should not use any sharing directory. It should be uploaded from the client machine. But it shows path undefined. Is there any other way to make the image uploading from the client side. Please respond soon yar..

Comment: For the clients to be able to download and display de image, you should provide some kind of public access, unless you're using some kind of athentication.

Saving the images in the public directory (or any subdirectory under _public_) is not a drawback for uploading them from the clients.